# Suggestions for storing homemade frozen custard

Tags: storage-method, custard

I've been having a hankering for Rita's ice cream because I love frozen custard. It's so much richer than vanilla ice cream. I've decided to try to make it myself with [this](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/old-fashioned-frozen-vanilla-custard/Detail.aspx) recipe.

I have the Cuisinart ice cream maker to mix it in. I'd like to make a big batch (quarts or gallon size would be good) of it can anyone recommend good storage containers? I would like one with a lid because I wouldn't want the custard to smell like "freezer" or get frozen crystals on top. Any tips or suggestions? Thanks!

Comments for other frozen custard recipes you've liked would be awesome too if you know of any! :)

Answer (score 1):

Any air tight plastic container will do to keep smells out. I use either cheap, disposable plastic leftover containers, or used ice cream tubs that I saved from previous purchased ice cream.

As for the crystallization- The only way to prevent that is my having no air in contact with the ice cream at all. I don't know how to solve that completely. I avoid the issue by not making more than we can eat in a reasonable amount of time (a week or so).